# No "Add New Table" option in Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 Version

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-data-tools

I can not able to add a new table in visual studio 2012.
I also try this Video from youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LaxjGixX9kU&t=117s
install SSDT from this site https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=36843
and l also install SSDT and try but no option available after installing SSDT so what can I do to Add a new Table? Please Help Me My Project is Stuck in this problem.

[Please help to enable adding a new table in visual studio 2012]

Comment: Are you really still using VS 2012?

Comment: Could we see a screenshot of your VStudio with SSDT project open, maybe a right-click where the "Add Table" menu is supposed to be showing up? My intuition is that you don't have the right kind of proj/solution open.